# What do you call a person who has an interest to be a lecturer or professor?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

If someone has interest (means that they are doing something to achieve that) in being an academic, such as a lecturer for a university, if that person is having educational qualifications which are suitable for that lecturer position and if that person has not become a lecturer yet and if his/her profession is something else now, what is the best word to call that person? Can he/she be called as **academic enthusiast**?

Answer (score 1):

Someone who has set a goal and is actively working towards it is *aspiring* to (toward?) said goal.

> as·pire *(verb)* direct one's hopes or ambitions toward achieving something.
>   *"we never thought that we might aspire to those heights"*
>   
> <sub>source [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aspire)</sub>

While used with a wide range of [aspirations](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aspirations), a common use is applied to struggling actors or artists.

Answer (score 1):

You can use that phrase, though I'd recommend you do that among friends and not on job materials. My answer will address commonly recognized titles within academia.

There is a term I've encountered at conferences for people who are not affiliated with a university but who do academic research: **[independent scholar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scholar#Independent_scholars)**. This substitutes for their affiliation, but it also serves as an ad hoc position title. They even have their own organizations, like the [National Coalition of Independent Scholars](https://www.ncis.org/).

While there is not necessarily a sense that independent scholars aspire to be university professors (some do, some don't), it would be preferable to *academic enthusiast* or *aspiring academic* in many job-related contexts. University departments are often looking to hire graduate students or post-docs as faculty. The title *enthusiast* sounds comparatively nonchalant and amateur compared to those positions, and *aspiring* sounds hopeful but insubstantial. (OK, so you aspire. What are you doing to get there?) At least in the US, Canada, and UK, hiring committees show a strong bias towards people who are *currently doing the work they would be hired for* in some way. This bias has led to phrases like "[publish or perish](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3999612/)" to describe the expectation of academic publishing to get or keep a job. Because hiring committees expect current competency and not hopefulness, I recommend avoiding *aspirational* language in any job materials or portfolios.

In comparison, **independent scholar** isn't a perfect term, but accompanied with a publication history it would demonstrate that the prospective applicant is serious about their work. Other terms that might be used include **prospective faculty** (used by [several](https://provost.wfu.edu/faculty/prospective-faculty/) [university](https://www.wellesley.edu/provost/prospectivefac) [websites](https://faculty.williams.edu/articles/fast-facts-for-prospective-faculty/)) and **faculty candidate** (often applied internally by universities to applicants for faculty positions; also used generally as a label for [people](https://www.aiche.org/community/sites/che-faculty-candidates-resource-center/announcements/are-you-faculty-candidate-looking-job-0) on the faculty job market). In other words, I recommend picking explanations that signal how you're one step away from the next position.